# Proving exact sequence of abelian groups splits

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, exact-sequence

I ran across this question on an old University of Maryland Algebra qual (1993, 4a):

> Consider an exact sequence of abelian groups $0\rightarrow \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow B \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_6\rightarrow 0$. Show that $B\cong \mathbb{Q}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_6$.

I know that there are examples of exact sequences of abelian groups which do *not* split, such as $0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow 0$, so my guess is that the presence of $\mathbb{Q}$ plays a role in the existence of a back-map from $B$, although I've had no luck thus far in constructing it.

Comment: Do you know that $\Bbb{Q}$ is an injective abelian group?

Comment: The proof that $\mathbb Q$ is injective (i.e. there is a splitting map $B \to \mathbb Q$) usually goes through [Baer's criterion](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Baer%27s+criterion).

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín, that's an interesting question, because according to the curriculum as it is now, one would not be expected to know $\mathbb{Q}$ is an injective abelian group (since little to no category theory is assumed, but it was in the 90's). If there is no other method which does not rely on Baer's criterion to infer this back-map, then you could flesh out your idea and I'll accept it as an answer. (I see that this back-map would fall out immediately, in this case.)

Comment: The way to approach this (showing a sequence is exact) without acquaintance on injective modules or homological stuff, is simply to consider a maximal subgroup among those not intersecting the kernel and conclude it is a direct summand. Hint here: first start with $C_6$ (the cyclic quotient) replaced with $C_2$ or $C_3$: in that cases, assume by contradiction that $B$ is torsion-free and conclude.